# Возникла проблема, в том что при конвертировании python файла в exe файл не получается загрузить пакет "pyttsx3.drivers"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Да, знаю что ответ нужно искать в документации, но прочитав о добавление пакетов толком не чего не понял.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\weakref.py", line 134, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "stancik.py", line 243, in <module>
File "stancik.py", line 54, in speak
File "pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
File "pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
File "pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers'
[3900] Failed to execute script stancik
```

Answer (score 1):

С проблемой разобрался. Для тех кто как и я столкнется с этой проблемой, попробуйте создать spec файл вашей программы

```
pyi-makespec название файла.py
```

Откройте этот файл и в кортеж hiddenimports вставьте то чего вам не хватает, в моем случае модуль pyttsx3.drivers и pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5

```
hiddenimports=['pyttsx3.drivers', 'pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5'],
```

После этого соберите exe файл с помощью spec файла

```
pyinstaller название файла.spec
```